# What is the difference between dharma and religion?

Tags: dharma, translation-request, other-religions, terminology

Hinduism is called "Dharma" unlike Christianity or Islam, which are called "religions".

My question is: What is the difference between Dharma and Religion?

Comment: I think 'Religion' is an english word misinterpreted by us as Dharma

Answer (score 19):

Western lexicons refer to all faiths of the world by the term "religion". Therefore, from a Western perspective, Hinduism is also known as one of the world's "religions". The reference to Hinduism as a religion is purely from a Western context. Thus, nothing is taken away when perceiving from that viewpoint.

However, to equate religion as an equivalent translation for "dharma" is incorrect. The word dharma itself has no equivalent Western word. And any translation, simplistic or scholarly, would fall short of fully justifying the original meaning of the word "dharma".

> Dharma has the Sanskrit root *dhri*, which means "that which upholds"
>   or "that without which nothing can stand" or "that which maintains the
>   stability and harmony of the universe." Dharma encompasses the
>   natural, innate behavior of things, duty, law, ethics, virtue, etc.
>   Every entity in the cosmos has its particular dharma ― from the
>   electron, which has the dharma to move in a certain manner, to the
>   clouds, galaxies, plants, insects, and of course, man. Man's
>   understanding of the dharma of inanimate things is what we now call
>   physics.
>
> British colonialists endeavored to map Indian traditions onto their
>   ideas of religion so as to be able to comprehend and govern their
>   subjects; yet the notion of dharma remained elusive. The common
>   translation into religion is misleading since, to most Westerners, a
>   genuine religion must:
>
> 1. be based on a single canon of scripture given by God in a precisely defined historical event;
> 2. involve worship of the divine who is distinct from ourselves and the cosmos;
> 3. be governed by some human authority such as the church;
> 4. consist of formal members;
> 5. be presided over by an ordained clergyman; and
> 6. use a standard set of rituals.
>
> But dharma is not limited to a particular creed or specific form of
>   worship. To the Westerner, an "atheistic religion" would be a
>   contradiction in terms, but in Buddhism, Jainism, and Carvaka dharma,
>   there is no place for God as conventionally defined. In some Hindu
>   systems the exact status of God is debatable. Nor is there only a
>   single standard deity, and one may worship one's own ishta-devata, or
>   chosen deity.
>
> Dharma provides the principles for the harmonious fulfillment of all
>   aspects of life, namely, the acquisition of wealth and power (artha),
>   fulfillment of desires (kama), and liberation (moksha). Religion,
>   then, is only one subset of dharma's scope.
>
> Religion applies only to human beings and not to the entire cosmos;
>   there is no religion of electrons, monkeys, plants and galaxies,
>   whereas all of them have their dharma even if they carry it out
>   without intention.

Source: [Dharma Is Not The Same As Religion](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/rajiv-malhotra/dharma-religion_b_875314.html) (by Rajiv Malhotra)

Comment: IMHO the answer is mostly correct, except for the use of word Dharma for Buddhism, Jainism or Charvaka philosophies. These are called 'Darshanas'. The more appropriate and closest meaning of Dharma in human context is 'duty' which a person needs to follow 'intentionally' for a society to sustain.

Comment: I would like to add that the above excerpt is taken from the book 'Being Different' by Rajiv Malhotra in case anyone would like to read more.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I don't have a copy of the book but is the entire answer taken from RM's book?

Comment: Not entirely @AmitSaxena See http://www.huffingtonpost.com/rajiv-malhotra/dharma-religion_b_875314.html for a detailed answer

Answer (score 6):

> Dharma and Religion are two very different things. Religion has its
>   origin in the west, by the followers of Abraham. Dharma has its origin
>   India. In religion we have single God, a Prophet or savior and a holy
>   book which alone is the way of liberation, whereas in dharma we have
>   many ways and all the ways leads to same God.  In Religion if one
>   doesn't believe in rules given by Prophet or savior then he is
>   considered as Heathen or Kafir. But in dharma everyone has a place, he
>   may even be an atheist like charvakas in hindu dharma.  I recommend
>   you to read these articles for details.

[Dharma and Religion - वेद Veda](http://veda.wikidot.com/dharma-and-religion)

[Dharma Is Not The Same As Religion](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/rajiv-malhotra/dharma-religion_b_875314.html?ir=India&adsSiteOverride=in)

Answer (score 1):

There  is  a  great  difference  between  a  religion  and  a  dharma.  A  religion  is  something  that  is  founded  by  someone.  A  religion  is  where  a  large  group  of  people  share  a  common  symbol,  a  common  religious  text,  a  common  GOD  and  a  common  founder.  A  religion  is  something  that  consists  of  a  group  of  followers  who  earlier  followed  a  different  faith  but  now  are  following  a  certain  faith  that  they  now  believe  in.  A  religion  is  one  which  was  founded  by  a  religious  movement.  A  religion  has  a  date  of  origin.  A  religion  is  a  set  of  belief  systems.

Dharma  on  the  other  hand  is  more  of  a  way  of  living  or  a  way  of  life  followed  since  antiquity,  i.e.,  since  the  start  of  civilisation.  Dharma  was  a  kind  of  education  or  knowledge  imparted  to  a  person  to  lead  a  life  in  a  certain  way.  Dharma  is  also  sometimes  considered  as  a  complete  and  continuous  education.  Dharma  is  based  on  the  principle  of  truth.  Dharma  is  based  on  various  stages  that  a  man  passes  through  in  his  lifetime,  i.e.,  birth,  childhood,  youth,  old  age  and  death.  Dharma  is  the  truth  or  Dharma  is  the  righteousness.  If  Karma  is  the  righteous  action,  Dharma  is  the  righteous  decision.  Dharma  is  not  preached.  Dharma  is  learnt,  followed  and  practised.  Dharma  is  the  role  you  play.

[Difference between Religion and Dharma](http://www.speakingtree.in/spiritual-blogs/seekers/philosophy/difference-between-religion-and-dharma)

Answer (score 1):

Each word has one 'etymological' meaning and one 'current usage' meaning. First let us see the etymological meaning of dharma.

According to the sanskritdictionary.com, the word 'dharma' originally means

> ध्रियते लोको$नेन, धरति लोकं वा (धृ-मन्;) : dhriyate loko'nena, dharati lokam vA, ie. by which the world is held or which holds the world.

According to the Oxford dictionary, the word 'Religion' originates from

> ‘life under monastic vows’,‘obligation, bond, reverence’, (perhaps based on Latin religare ‘to bind’).

'**Holding' and 'binding' are very close indeed** !  So there is some similarity in the etymological meanings of the two words, there is some dissimilarity though.

Next, let us come to the current usage. The sanskritdictionary.com provides the following meanings of 'Dharma':

> 1 **Religion**; **the customary observances of a caste, sect, &c**. -2 **Law, usage, practice, custom, ordinance,** statue. -3 Religious or moral merit, **virtue**, **righteousness**, good works (regarded as one of the four ends of human existence); अनेन धर्मः सविशेषमद्य मे त्रिवर्ग- सारः प्रतिभाति भाविनि Ku.5.38, and see त्रिवर्ग also; एक एव सुहृद्धर्मो निधने$प्यनुयाति यः H.1.63. -4 Duty, prescribed course of conduct; षष्ठांशवृत्तेरपि धर्म एषः Ś.5.4; Ms.1.114. -5 Right, justice, equity, impartiality. -6 Piety, propriety, decorum. -7 **Morality, ethics** -8 **Nature. disposition, character**; उत्पत्स्यते$स्ति मम को$पि समानधर्मा

The Oxford dictionary provides the following meanings of 'Religion'

> 1. **The belief in and worship of a superhuman controlling power, especially a personal God or gods.**
> 2. **A particular system of faith and worship.**
> 3. **A pursuit or interest followed with great devotion.**

Many of the 'current usage meanings' of both the words sound similar.

Some of  the meanings like 'Virtue', 'Duty', 'Righoutness', 'Nature' etc are of course entirely different.

This is a site where 'Hinduism' is an accepted word 'by default' and therefore 'Religion' can be a good translation of 'Dharma'. When used in some other sense, we can easily use some appropriate word like Virtue, Duty etc.

We must remember that the two words are coming from two different societies, traditions and culture and differences are obvious. **Such differences are inherent in almost each and every translation of Sanskrit words to English.**

**As we have accepted the English language to express our ideas about Spirituality, I think we can safely use the word 'Religion' for 'Dharma'** except certain cases where the word means something different as mentioned above.

To conclude, even though they are not exactly the same, they can be used interchangeably most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

In English, Hinduism is called a "religion".

In Hindi (and Sanskrit, I guess), Christianity and Islam are both called "dharma".

I'm not going to claim that "dharma" and "religion" mean *exactly* the same thing, because words for abstract things from different languages rarely mean exactly the same thing. Nonetheless, the English idea of "religion" is close enough to the Hindi/Sanskrit idea of "dharma" that we may as well treat them as interchangeable.

Comment: Sorry but it isnt correct http://veda.wikidot.com/dharma-and-religion

Comment: @NullPoiиteя What, exactly, is not correct?

Comment: @Kapil If you have a different answer, _post it as a different answer_.

Comment: There are at least 6 different equivalent functions relating to Dharma in English.