# Does karma have anything to do with the Lord we worship?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, moksha, other-religions, devi

Different people worship different forms of Lord. One worships Krishna while the other worships Lord Shiva. Does their previous karma related with the god they worship? If so, how

For example, Arjuna hasn't recognized Lord Shiva and battled with him in his birth as one of the Pandavas and therefore he is later born as Bhakta Kannappa. In a similar way does everyone have a similar story like this in their previous birth?

If so, what about the people born in religions like Buddhism, Christianity etc. Moksha is available in Hinduism but how do these religion followers get moksha? Why aren't they given a chance to get moksha?

Comment: yes karma certainly has a lot to do with it. Usually great saints and even God when they come down to Earth they begin to call those beings who had previous relationships with them. But faith can change all. One who has steadfastness and really wants God, then the saint (maybe your Guru) or if needed even God Himself will manifest and take you into His fold.

Comment: As for people from different religions, there is no wrong path to Moksha, except thinking that the other's path is wrong. There are many ways to fly to USA, one can go through British Airways, one can go through Ethihad. The goal is the same. Similarly all religions are valid. All religions speak the same truth, but take different paths to Brahman. This is the message that was preached by some great saints such as Sri Ramakrishna, Saint Kabir Das, Sri Sai Baba (Shirdi Sai and Sathya Sai Baba), Saint Paramhamsa Yogananda, Lord Vivekananda and so on. God is One. This Advaitist thought.

Comment: @Sai I profoundly disagree with the sentiment that all religions are equally valid.  I certainly agree that there are many different paths to get Moksha, but that doesn't mean all possible paths will lead you to Moksha.  To take an extreme example, going around killing as many people as you can will not get you Moksha.  Now there's no religion that advocates that, but that's just to illustrate that just because a religion advocates something doesn't mean that's a path that will actually get you to Moksha.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan you are free to disagree with the sentiments of Sri Ramakrishna and other saints whom I have mentioned. However let me ask you this, from which part of my comment did you get the "killing as many people" part? I never mentioned anything like that. I just meant to say that different religions are different paths to God. As for "Just because a religion advocates something doesn't mean that's a path that will actually get you moksha" Theoretically yes. but practically tell me, which religion advocates the wrong path and we shall discuss in chat because this is Hinduism.SE.

Comment: @Sai Lots of Hindu scriptures discuss how Mleccha (foreign) faiths lead people to commit sins, because such faiths have incorrect lists of good deeds and bad deeds. So someone who simply tries to live a good life in accordance with a religion that emphasizes action would not attain Moksha through Karma Yoga if he doesn't realize what actions are actually right. Similarly, if you're relying an incorrect understanding of reality, then you wouldn't attain Moksha through Jnana Yoga, because then the knowledge you'd acquire would be factually incorrect, etc.  It's because of objectivity of truth.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan it is true about wrong knowledge (factually incorrect, etc) and incorrect understanding, etc. But that has nothing to do with religion. Whatever religion you may be in, even Hinduism, if you do not understand the inner essence behind things and have a wrong knowledge then you are not going to get Moksha. Same goes for other religions. Just because all religions are valid does not mean that every single follower of every religion has a core understanding of its essence. But this does not invalidate the religion itself. This is getting lengthy so a chat maybe the best :)

Comment: @Sai It boils down to this: religions can give factually incorrect information about the nature of reality and the like to their followers.  Lots of Hindu scriptures say this about Mleccha religions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan the one who has not delved deep into the religion cannot judge that it is invalid. Only when once goes deep into both Hinduism and the Religion Z will He realize that both speak of the same thing. The one who sees the external insignia of religions will believe that one is valid and the other is invalid. The one who has actually done deep investigation into both, will realize the truth in unity of all mankind and the unity of all religion.

Comment: The one from another religion who reads the texts in ours will believe that ours is factually incorrect. And we believe theirs is factually incorrect. This is because each one is an expert in their own religion but reads the other's religion with a closed mind and therefore fails to grasp the unity. This argument can go on and on. But I am suggesting that one can have an open mind and try to understand that the road to God is not a one-way road, there are many possible ways. Perhaps some are more bumpy, some quicker, but they lead to God and God alone.

Comment: I like advaitist thoughts. But, I would like to clarify the meaning stated by the Lord Krishna, that *material desires may be fulfilled by worshipping demigods but to get moksha one must worship me*?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Do you think people from Mleccha religion can't reach God? You are absolutely wrong.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Remember God doesn't have a religion nor does our soul have one. When one is sincere enough to find God, one who has full faith in him then no matter what his/her religion is, they will reach Moksha.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, they can attain Moksha by switching religions, but not by staying with their Mleccha religion.  So yeah, if they're sincere in their quest for truth, then either in this birth or some subsequent birth they will find out that the Vedas are the truth.   I'm just saying that the paths prescribed in Mleccha religions do not lead to Moksha.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

As the soul elevates / ascends itself in each birth, through karmic good actions, teachers / gurus corresponding to the state of mind, would summon to guide you further.  Worshipping the same god or different god has no specific relevance for there is no conflict between Gods and conflict is within human mind and heart.

Moksha is word often used in its diluted state nowadays.  One attains moksha or liberation after 84 lakhs of birth & rebirths (based on certain assumptions, as per Kathopanishad).

There are seven more lokas or astral worlds, after clearing debts in one world, the soul migrates to next world and has to nullify karma of that world to go to next.

After clearing all 7 lokas, then what happens is mokhsa final merging with Ultimate truth or god himself.  This final stage is called moksha and not one promotion to another world/loka...

On cursory look, Gautam Buddha, Moses, Jesus, got realization after/within 40 days of penance.  Looks simple and easy.  But to reach to that stage, they have went many births / rebirths that their punya got "phal" (fructified).

On a lighter note, one day penance by a modern day person will land him 40 days of hospitalization, such is our body state.  Think of those saints, sitting under tree, motionless, meditating with concentration with no link or feel of external world around them, while we cannot concentrate on our text books without switching off the radio FM music !! see the contrast in concentration.

God has no form and yet he is in every form !!  God has no religion, he visits all humble seekers.

Just a kindergarten child with each passing year moves to next class with new teachers, similarly, as soul ascends, teachers come to play their role.

Once, you reach an yogic state, then the Guru would remain same across different lokas for a true guru is a god realized soul  (read Sri Paramahansa Yogananda - Autobiography of a Yogi), which explains beautifully these aspects.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does their previous karma related with the god they worship?*

Karma has nothing to do with the lord we worship. In Gita, lord says that the *Movement of Karma is extremely complex (Gahan)*.
Ultimately whomsoever we worship based on our *Prakriti*(nature), be it demigods or (internal) demons or ghosts (past events); it ultimately goes to the supreme soul only.

> *...does everyone have a similar story like this in their previous birth?*

May be or may not be. But it's not important.

[BG 9.25](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/25)

> Those who worship the demigods will take birth among the demigods;
>   those who worship the ancestors go to the ancestors; those who worship
>   ghosts and spirits will take birth among such beings; and those who
>   worship Me will live with Me.

We tend to become what we think or worship or act upon. Unless the worship or *Yajna* is not towards the supreme soul, we continue to be in the cycle of birth and death.

> *If so, what about the people born in religions like Buddhism,
>   Christianity etc. Moksha is available in Hinduism but how do these
>   religion followers get moksha? Why aren't they given a chance to get
>   moksha?*

Not a single religion has any authority over Moksha. Also remember that [Religion is not *Dharma*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/336/1049).

If a person sees supreme soul or *Parama Brahman* in Jesus or Buddha and offers complete devotion to them, then ofcourse they achieve Moksha. It's similar to others seeing supreme soul in Krishna or Shiva. Krishna, Shiva, Jesus, Buddha are embodied mediums (*Saakar*) to easily realize *Brahman*. Similarly a Muslim genuinely worshipping formless god *Nirakar Brahman*, finally attains *Moksha*.

However, if we pray to all these gods with material desires in mind (*Rajasic* worship) then actually it's just a namesake worship, but ultimately we are praying their demigod or may be even demon forms only. Such people don't attain *Moksha*.

[BG 4.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/12)

> Men in this world desire success in fruitive activities, and therefore
>   they worship the demigods. Quickly, of course, men get results from
>   fruitive work in this world.

Example: A person realizing supreme soul in Jesus may get *Moksha* than a person rather than seeking fruits from Krishna.

Do you see any god specific affiliation in below sloka?

[BG 4.23](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/23)

> The work of a man who is unattached to the modes of material nature
>   and who is fully situated in transcendental knowledge merges entirely
>   into transcendence.