# Killing animals, Karma and our birth

Tags: belief, gods, bhagavad-gita, karma, non-vegetarian

My question has two different aspects.

1. In Hindu religion, it is considered bad to kill animals, but in Islam it is said that animals are just for our use e.g., use them as food, transport etc. (meaning there's nothing wrong in killing them)
2. Now in this particular scenario, a boy who's born into a Muslim family will definitely eat non-vegetarian food (which is definitely a sin)

Now my question is, if our birth and death are decided by God (according to the Bhagavad Gita: 'I am the creator of all the living beings'), then why does he let anyone born into a Muslim family? A person born into such a family will always commit a sin and bad karma.

Comment: I want to remember on thing that never ever compare Hindu religion with others. Hindu religion is a life style but all others are really based on single person life or a small community

Answer (score 5):

Pay close attention to below slokas from [Bhagavad Gita]:
[BG 3.10, 3.11, 3.12, 13](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3)

> — In the beginning of creation, the Lord of all creatures (Brahma) sent
>   forth **generations of men and demigods**, along with sacriﬁces for
>   Viṣṇu, and blessed them by saying, “Be thou happy by this yajña
>   [sacriﬁce] because its performance will bestow upon you everything
>   desirable for living happily and achieving liberation.”
>
> — The demigods, being pleased by sacriﬁces, will also please you, and
>   thus, by cooperation between men and demigods, prosperity will reign
>   for all.
>
> — In charge of the various necessities of life, the demigods, being
>   satisﬁed by the performance of **yajña [sacriﬁce]**, will supply all
>   necessities to you. **But he who enjoys such gifts without offering them
>   to the demigods in return is certainly a thief.**
>
> The devotees of the Lord are released from all kinds of sins because
>   they eat food which is offered ﬁrst for sacriﬁce. **Others, who prepare
>   food for personal sense enjoyment, verily eat only sin**.

The answer to your question lies within above slokas if you understood those, then no need to read below. If not convinced then before understanding my answer, first consider the below terms.

### 1. Dharma (not religion)

[This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/341/1049) explains nicely: Dharma is actually a *righteous duty*. Every element of universe has its own *Dharma*. Except humans, most of the elements follow their duty but without being conscious about it. If a human follows own Dharma consciously then attains liberation.
e.g. a person might be born Muslim/Vaishnav/Non-believer, but his Dharma depends on his work & nature. For example, if he is in science then BrahminDharma, in army then KshatriyaDharma, in business then VaishyaDharma and doing job (any field) then ShudraDharma.
Similarly, a person has to have SwamiDharma towards his wife, but PitaDharma towards his children and PutraDharma towards parents.

### 2. Devta (demigods)

If you look at the Indian philosophy, each element of nature is associated with a demigod. e.g. *Water => Varun*, *Air => Vayu*, *Earth => Bhoomidevi*, *Light => Suryadev*, *Humans => Narayan*, ***Animals ==> [Pashupati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupati)*** and so on.
When a demigod gets disturbed, it creates a havoc. In other words, *Tsunami* can be considered as *Varun dev is angry*. The demigods have to be pleased by maintaining their equilibrium; temples are just *gentle reminders*.
e.g. People end up worshiping Pashupati in Nepal temple instead of seeing him in animals all over the world.

### 3. Yajña/Yagna (Sacrifice)

```
यज्ञ = योग्य त्याग
```

In modern times, we have mistakenly limited the term Yagna with only *Dharmik activity of Hom-Havan*. In reality, it is just 1 way of doing it.

*If one does his prescribed(योग्य) duty(धर्म) by sacrificing(त्याग) the deviations, then it is [Yagna](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/47)*.
e.g. if a student pays attention to study by sacrificing the thoughts of playing then he is doing (Shram) Yagna. Similarly, a boy does Brahmacharya Yagna until he marries his wife.

Refer to various ways of Yagna in
[BG 4.25-4.31](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4).

> — Some yogīs perfectly worship the demigods by offering different
>   sacriﬁces to them, and some offer sacriﬁces in the ﬁre of the Supreme
>   Brahman.
>
> — Some [the unadulterated brahmacārīs] sacriﬁce the hearing process
>   and the senses in the ﬁre of mental control, and others [the regulated
>   householders] sacriﬁce the objects of the senses in the ﬁre of the
>   senses.
>
> — Others, who are interested in achieving self-realization through
>   control of the mind and senses, offer the functions of all the senses,
>   and of the life breath, as oblations into the ﬁre of the controlled
>   mind.
>
> — Having accepted strict vows, some become enlightened by sacriﬁcing
>   their possessions, and others by performing severe austerities, by
>   practicing the yoga of eightfold mysticism, or by studying the Vedas
>   to advance in transcendental knowledge.
>
> — Still others, who are inclined to the process of breath restraint to
>   remain in trance, practice by offering the movement of the outgoing
>   breath into the incoming, and the incoming breath into the outgoing,
>   and thus at last remain in trance, stopping all breathing. Others,
>   curtailing the eating process, offer the outgoing breath into itself
>   as a sacriﬁce.
>
> — All these performers who know the meaning of sacriﬁce become
>   cleansed of sinful reactions, and, having tasted the nectar of the
>   results of sacriﬁces, they advance toward the supreme eternal
>   atmosphere.
>
> — O best of the Kuru dynasty, without sacriﬁce one can never live
>   happily on this planet or in this life: what then of the next?

### Conclusion

So combine all of above to come to a conclusion. When the Yagna is performed according to own duty(स्वधर्म), then the demigods are pleased and the nature's equilibrium is maintained.

Also refer my answer to below question, where I explain scientifically why non-veg is not preferable in most cases:
[Should a Brahmin be Vegetarian](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/should-a-brahmin-be-vegetarian/8218#8218).

But have ATTENTION: It doesn't literally mean that killing animals & eating meat is bad and eating veg food is good.

### Answer

When someone eats meat or even vegetarian (un)knowingly, is he/she helping maintaining nature's equilibrium? In other words, is he pleasing to Pashupati dev or Bhoomidevi?

It depends.

*1 -- A tribal staying in Alaska, African, Andaman have no choice but to depend on killing and eating animal. They please Pashupati, because by killing those animals they keep the number in check and also by protecting the forest resources for harvesting. (Killing too many is wrong though)*

*2 -- A CEO maintains strictly vegetarian diet and daily gets his favorite veg dish by sending driver 10 km away from his office at lunch time. He might be pleasing Bhoomidevi, but he violates (pollutes) Vaayu devta! Realizing this petrol waste, he then starts eating in office canteen. But wastes food daily due to taste dislike. Now he angers Bhoomi devi!*

Coming back to that Muslim boy. If he is eating non-veg food, then definitely he is (un)knowingly committing sin. Because in modern time, availability/nutrition/nature-preserve/varieties of vegetarian food is quite vast, which leaves very less room for non-veg food. Land - Bhoomi devi is wasted for harvesting non-veg.

So everyone's (irrespective of religion) Maanav Dharma is to adopt or try Vegetarianism!

Comment: Please consider adding a TL;DR at the top ;)

Comment: @sv., usually I try to do a poetic justice to my answer. In this case, the Gita verses were good enough to decipher the meaning, hence I mentioned those as answer, so that one can DR. But then if someone doesn't get that, will have to go through all the TL; part. :-)

Comment: @iammilind :- please guid on this :- http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12156/worship-of-one-god-and-worship-of-shri-ram