# Consuming milk and dairy causes bad karma?

Tags: karma, cows

Since it is get from the exploitation of innocents mammals, consuming milk and dairy causes bad karma?

Comment: In Ancient days, people in India generally used to feed calves first and then remaining milk was used by owner of cows. Now, people started exploiting everything and the exploitation may give you tiny amount of bad karma.

Comment: The havi that is poured in yagna to satiate the Gods is ghee & that comes from cow's milk.So,obtaining milk from cows is certainly NOT a sinful act(that involves bad karma).Of course let the calves drink their share first. ;)

Comment: Seems that you are specifically asking some good thought provoking questions on Morality with regards to animals! Remember that Morality changes from person to person, though it should be uniform in a decent society. Here is 1 related question: [Killing animals, Karma and our birth](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8510/1049)

Comment: If we stop taking milk from cows. The Breast part of them become hard and for calves it is hard to grab milk and even sometime breast regularly stops milking. It will lead to the unhealthfulness of cattles

Comment: @PonmariSubramanian That must be true since it is evident that a cow's duty doesn't end with feeding her own calves .But where you got that info from?

Comment: @AnilKumar has the right answer, Milk left over by the calves can be consumed by humans.

Comment: If mammals stop sharing their milk, it will leads to change the milk state from liquid to solid and may lead to have lung cancer disease and all.It is just a general source.It is applicable to women also.In Tamil,they used to say as 'Muram thadiduchi' which means 'something stops the water(milk) path'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer is based  on the info found on [this](http://www.hinduism.co.za/cowsare.htm) page.

From Mahabharata Anusasana Parva

> Bhishma said: No sacrifice can be performed without the aid of curds
>   and ghee (clarified butter). The very character of sacrifice which
>   sacrifices have, depends upon ghee. Hence ghee (or, the cow from which
>   it is produced) is regarded as the very root of sacrifice.

Hence, it is evident that one of the purposes for which cows exist is to produce milk from which ghee can be made.Hence it is evident enough that the act of obtaining milk from cows can't create bad karma.Instead it is good karma since you are aiding in agnihotra(fire sacrifice) which is essential for sustaining the Demi Gods  who in turn sustains life.

More from the link.

> Cows have been said to be the limbs of sacrifice. They represent
>   sacrifice itself. Without them, there can be no sacrifice. With their
>   milk and the Havi produced therefrom, they uphold all creatures by
>   diverse acts. Cows are guileless in their behaviour. From them flow
>   sacrifices and Havya and Kavya, and milk and curds and ghee. hence
>   cows are sacred.

Let's now see what saints have to say on consuming or using cow milk.From the same link :

**Vyasa said:**

> Cows are sacred. They are embodiments of merit. They are high and most
>   efficacious cleansers of all. .....**For the next three days one should
>   drink the hot milk of the cow**. Having thus drunk for three days hot
>   milk, one should next drink hot ghee for three days. Having in this
>   way drunk hot ghee for three days, one should subsist for the next
>   three days on air only.

So when a self realised Rishi like Vyasa is recommending drinking milk the act of obtaining milk from cows can't result in bad karma.

**Vasishtha said:**

> By bathing in water mixed with cow-dung, people shall become
>   sanctified.... Cows are the best Havi for the deities. The Mantras
>   called Swaha and Vashat are forever established in cows. Sacrifices
>   are established in the cows. Cows constitute the fruit of
>   sacrifices.Cows are the future and the past, and Sacrifices rest on
>   them. Morning and evening cows yield unto the Rishis, Havi for use in
>   Homa......**Cows are the mothers of the universe**.*

So, again, it is quite evident from the above quote that being the mother of the entire universe a cow's duty is to feed everyone with her milk and not alone her own calves.Such is the greatness of cows.

I'm concluding my answer with another Bhisma's quote:

> Cows are the mothers of the universe The human infant is fed breast
>   milk by its human mother for under three years. After weaning, the cow
>   acts as the surrogate mother providing milk for the rest of the human
>   life-through childhood, adult age and old age. Cow is verily the
>   mother of the world.

So, obtaining milk from cow is in no way a bad karma provided you are not forcing her or inflicting pain on her in any form.Also ,her calves should not be deprived.

Comment: You can add [this link](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b045.htm) to Anushasana Parva in your answer.

Comment: @sv. How and where shall i add that link?.Coz i have based my answer on the linked page.The quotes are found on that page.