# What is the moral stance towards milking of animals/cows?

Tags: dharma, animals, food, cows, ethics

The chief function of lactation is to provide nutrition and immune protection to the young after birth. Consuming milk of the mother (e.g., cow), meant for her offspring strikes to be a heinous deed. It suggests as a thoughtless act of making progeny suffer as well as considerable possibility of mother's distress.

---

Difference from [Consuming milk and dairy causes bad karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/consuming-milk-and-dairy-causes-bad-karma/)

Karma refers to aftereffects + intent of an action. The aforementioned Question and it's answer is focused primarily on former part. While this question addresses later concern solely.

Comment: I don't understand the question here and also the relation to it with Hinduism. Can you explain?

Comment: Yu can ask this question on [vegetarianism.se]. It's more relevant there.

Comment: cow is the supreme source of all yagnas (sacrifices) because they cannot be performed without ghee (which comes from butter which comes from milk). So, it is not a heinous deed. In fact, not milking cows to perform duties laid down in shastras, would be a heinous deed. However, there are strict rules about when to milk them without causing suffering - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/when-hindus-buy-milk-are-they-required-to-only-buy-milk-from-cows-that-are-not-s/20895#20895

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It is _implicit_ that Hinduism perspective is sought by posting it here.

Comment: But it is not clear. It is just asking for morality which is not specific to Hinduism. In the title you ask the question and in the body there's no question and just your opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consuming milk and dairy causes bad karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/consuming-milk-and-dairy-causes-bad-karma)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Though I'm relatively new to SE but repeating the question in the body seems absurd to me. As well as, I agree 'morality isn't specific to Hinduism' however posting a question in Hinduism.SE is considerably specific to Hinduism.

Comment: Title is not the entire question. It is just an intro to your main question. The question should be in the body. Your question's body should explain in detail what your question is. [What should I write in the question body if the title already explains everything?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145019/357396). Some people tend to write their question in the title and write their opinion in the body or self answer in the body. Your question doesn't look different to me. But that shouldn't be the way. Take a look at [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am answering this wrt cows milk, not milk of other animals like goat, camel etc.

As stated here in [SB 8.8.11](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/11):

> Pañca-gavya, the five products received from the cow, namely milk,
>   yogurt, ghee, cow dung and cow urine, are required in all ritualistic
>   ceremonies performed according to the Vedic directions.

So it's an important ingredient to perform vedic rituals. Also cow milk was meant for consumption as cows produce more milk than it needs to feed it's calf but humans are to consume the milk only after the calves had their share.

Quoting from an article posted on bhaktivedantamanor.co.uk [here](http://bhaktivedantamanor.co.uk/newgokul/index.php/cowprotection/if-you-drink-milk/):

> A point of consideration is that milk is a food sanctioned and
>   designed by God, by Krishna, for humans and not just for the calf. The
>   cow produces more milk than the calf needs and this is not accidental
>   but by design. To get milk from a cow you need to impregnate the cow
>   (there are numerous examples where some cows gave milk without
>   impregnation but that is another story) and after a pregnancy of nine
>   months a calf will be born and the cow will produce milk. Out of
>   affection for her calf the cow will give as much milk as possible. The
>   first milk is full of colostrum and this will give the best start to
>   the calf. After about five days the milk looks normal and this is then
>   suitable for us to drink. The milk is for the calf and for us.

Read the purpose of Surabhi (cow) as explained here [SB 8.8.2](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/8/2):

> These cows are the Lord’s pet animals. From the surabhi cows one can
>   take as much milk as one needs, and one may milk these cows as many
>   times as he desires. In other words, the surabhi cow can yield milk
>   unlimitedly. Milk is necessary for the performance of yajña. Sages
>   know how to use milk to elevate human society to the perfection of
>   life.

Citing another quote to support the above statement [Satapatha Brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe44/sbe44121.htm#fr_1261) Part V (SBE44):

> 14:2:1:99. He then lets the calf to it (to suck), with, 'Pûshan thou
>   art,'--Pûshan, doubtless, is he that blows here (the wind), for that
>   one supports (push) all this (universe); and the Pravargya also is
>   that (wind): it is him he thus pleases, and therefore he says, 'Pûshan
>   thou art.'
>
> 14:2:1:1010. He then leads it (the calf) away with, 'Afford (milk)
>   for the Gharma!' for the Gharma, doubtless, is that fluid which this
>   (cow) lets flow: he thus means to say thereby, 'Allow her a share!'

Comment: Instead of putting"here", you should name the website and say where it will take the users to.  Putting links under "Here" should be avoided.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Done :)