# Do Any Tantra Texts Promote Veganism Or Being Vegan

Tags: tantra, food

Been part of the vegan environmentalist movement for many years now, just wondering if any Tantra texts encourage or promote being vegan ? Cause of Shakta path, am more on the Tantra side w/ Hindu texts. Thx !

Edit : This is my post from a deleted account [Do scriptures provide any guidelines or any information for vegan puja and rites?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52091/do-scriptures-provide-any-guidelines-or-any-information-for-vegan-puja-and-rites?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C43.0562) Doesn’t say in the comments/reply about Tantra specifically.

Comment: Veganism isn't present in Indian traditions, as dairy wasn't considered problematic or an act of hiṁsā towards the cattle, because there was no dairy industry in earlier times, nor there was beef industry as such.

Comment: Why traditions like Jaina didn't avoid consuming dairy because in early times,  cows were treated in a much more humane manner on family farms, and it did not harm the animal as such, the cows weren't forced to produce milk more than they could, and calves weren't separated from mother and given their share of milk, the male calves upon growing up went to the farm or for transportation and the female for milk production. With the dairy industry having “industrialized” milk production more than ever, there is much more harm caused now to them though.

Comment: @Bingming Thx, that makes sense. I wonder if any lost or obscure Hindu texts talk about it. Factory farming is so horrible, the abuse and exploitation of animals is so messed up  But veganism movement seems to be growing. The more huge it gets, the more it will prevent animal suffering.

Comment: @devibhakt Afaik Hindu Scriptures mainly divide foods into 3 categories of Gunas a)Sattva-mode of goodness b) Raja-mode of passion c) Tama- mode of ignorance .Milk we get nowadays as mentioned by Bingming  is produced by acts of hiṁsā towards the cattle so they can be termed as Tamasic. Some hindu texts mention(can't remember exact source :( ) that we are forbidden to drink milk of cows within 10 days of it giving birth to a calf.

Comment: @Rāmachandra Thx, that makes sense. The more I’ve found out about the reality of the abuse & exploitation of animals, the more and more I’ve gone all the way over to the animal liberation side of the vegan movement (trying to buy makeup not tested on animals, trying to buy clothes & decor that are totally vegan, looking up all vegan recipes for food, etc) Hindu texts are so numerous and lots of interpolation, misunderstandings are there, so much contradictions in what is said. But still, some stuff seems so clearly right & wrong, so obvious what is unethical immoral versus what is good, right.