# What is the purpose of life?

Tags: karma, life, creation

This question may be childish or even rubbish but I have had this doubt for a long time.

According to my religion, Hinduism (Sanathana Dharma), God has created all from grass to all forms of life. Then why he did create heaven and hell because if he/she/it (refers to God - Peculiarly Shiva) creates every person as a good one then he/she/it can prevent sending people to hell.

According to a famous psychologist:

> Situations and surroundings are the only factors which convert a good person to a bad one

So why does God create a bad situation and thereby creating a bad person?

I am a strong believer in Hinduism so I know there's some purpose behind this, what is that?

---

EDIT:

- Why does God need a servant then?
- If he can create everything then why does he create bad things and make his servants suffer?

My strong questions:

- **Why does God alone enjoy everything in the heaven?**
- **Why limited period of time (in heaven) for people?** 
  This is complete injustice. I know He created us and he has a right to destroy us so I am not going to speak here.
- **But why he is willing that people suffer?**

Comment: This is too complex a question to ask and a proper answer can fill pages of a whole book .

Comment: Oh I see could you share some of your ideas please?

Comment: Very good question sir! We are all suffering because of ignorance. Ignorance of what? Ignorance of our true Nature. What is this True Nature. We are immortal Atma! We're eternal and divine! But we think that we are the body, mind, etc. Thus we suffer. Imagine that you are going along with your best friend for a movie. In the movie, the hero wakes up, eats his breakfast, goes to office, eats lunch, and sleeps. That's it, movie over. What you will say: "Waste of money! No action, no drama, no excitement". That's life. Life is a giant movie. God is the director. All are playing their roles.

Comment: The realized saints, watch life as a giant movie. Everything is illusion or Maya. Nobody really suffering. Everybody is just playing their roles. In fact, everyone is Divine! This is the culmination of all knowledge. The purpose of life is to simply go through our life experience. Every experience is beautiful and rewarding, if seen through the lens of Knowledge. Heaven and hell are all temporary, nothing is permanent. To be really happy, one has to realize who He is. To realize who He is, determination and courage are necessary. Three ways: Self-enquiry (jnana), faith (bhakti) and detachment.

Comment: @sv. Very good question. That question would require extensive discussion of philosophy. So basically what every vedantin will tell is that 'jiva are eternal, they have been in existence since ever, so whatever karma you have dictates whether you suffer or pleasure, with karma having no beginning and no end, until Self-realization'. So IMHO that question is basically the classic 'why' debate. You just have to stop at a point stating 'thats just how it is'. Hence my focus on realizing the Self, thereby realizing that there is no suffering, than going through endless why's. :)

Comment: Answer: "no purpose". @sv., Will try few more "why"s (all from Gita): Assume at beginning, there is "Nothing" (no shape, no quality). This "Nothing" can't reside anywhere, because there is nothing. This "Nothing" is God. The identification of this "Nothing" results in 'Something'; which 'magically' becomes "Everything". This "Everything" is still God, but full of contradictions to be able to summed up to "Nothing". Momentarily, imagine this "Everything" to be an entity to continuously changing shapes. Here "Shape = Universe" & "Change of Shape = Time". We perceive these changes systematic. (1)

Comment: This "Everything"'s has supreme consciousness at its core. By threading, it generates many consciousnesses. The intention of these newly generated consciousnesses is to enjoy "Everything" until they intend to return to the supreme one. As these consciousness passes through the continuous shape changer "Everything", they get influenced in various ways. Some get quickly get enough of it and return back, Some get dumbed down, some wants to explore, some want to enjoy and so on. Now this "enjoy" here can relate to every aspect of "Everything". heaven/pleasure or hell/pain, all are enjoyable. (2)

Comment: As @sai said, we don't go to cinema to watch simple video recording, but for a movie with interesting things. We want to get excited in various ways: Horror, Gore, Romance and so on. So that's 1 reply to "why". It's just a perception of being joyful, worried, sad; but at core we are always "enjoyers". When this enjoyment no longer excites our consciousness, it returns to from where it threaded & merges back(*Moksha*). BTW, periodically anyway all the consciousnesses would merge back to supreme one and "Everything" will become "Nothing". We need not worry about Moksha, bcoz it's not a goal! (3)

Comment: @sv. Well that's again a very good question. The thing is, this Earth is not the only planet in this Universe, just think about all of Creation. The scriptures give verses about the various lokas that exist in Creation, each with its own diverse life. How can one conclude, about the total population of the Universe, let alone Creation, with just the (human) population on Earth? Does it remain same? Does it increase? Does it decrease? Thus the vedantins simply say 'it is so', and then move on to the other question: 'Who Am I?'. All questions end in this big question, according to Advaita. :).

Comment: @everyone, Is this process endless? I mean reincarnation cycle

Comment: @VISWESWARAN1998 There are three possible ways (out of many others) to get out of the cycle of reincarnation. 1. Knowledge of self. The knowledge of self destroys all tendencies and roots out reincarnation. 2. Surrender. The Lord is the sole refuge for all and he denies no-one. He assures us that the One who surrenders to Him, will be freed from all bad karmas and will attain moksha. 3. Detachment, the one who is desireless and detached, will not be affected by anything, and will thus end the reincarnation cycle, for there is no longer good/bad in his perspective. All the best.

Comment: VISWESWARAN, Rephrasing(3): Reincarnation stops(*Moksha*) once we are indifferent to material universe(*MAyA*). @sv. Not only spiritual goals, but even material goals are also perfectly fine. But contradict those goals too. "Set goals, yet no goals." We act according to *SwaDharma* (collection of *Dharma*s associated with self), yet ultimately leave behind all these *Dharma*s. If we stuck to something, it's bound to break. Contradicting self is bit more manageable than letting the external factors do it. In different words, nothing should be taken too seriously, though it appears dead serious!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35543/discussion-on-question-by-visweswaran1998-what-is-the-purpose-of-life).

Answer (score 6):

Well, according to Bhagavan Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, the goal of human life is to realise God and become one with Him, for He alone has the ability to grant us perennial bliss. Of course, it is God alone who has created everything, but again, it is he who has made some rules to govern this world. And these rules are cosmic in nature. The world runs on Karma theory. So if you do good to others, you are rewarded and vice-versa. When you look at the world thru the prism of Karma, probably, you can understand what I am trying to say. If, as per what you say, God creates a bad person, it is the same God who creates a good person also. Isn't it? The concept of Heaven in Hinduism is very subtle Some think that Heaven is the destination for all of us, but that is also a place that is not permanent. Based on your good karma, you stay there and once your good karma ends, you come back to earth and again start earning good karma. Similarly with hell. So as true seekers of knowledge or God, we should aim at a point of no return, or in other words, our real Nature, our own Atman!