# Were there any other religions during the treta and dwapar yuga?

Tags: vedas, history

I know that sanatana dharma is the oldest religion. But are there any evidences or any mentions of other religions in the vedas?
If yes,what were the religions?

Comment: Jainism is world's 2nd oldest religion. It is in existence since Satya Yuga. Their first Tirthankar - Rishabhadeva was incarnation of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: [(*SanAtan*) *Dharma* is not Religion](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/341/1049). *Shaivism* & *Vaishnavism* were 2 of the old religions, which are now combined in *Hinduism*. *Buddhism* & *Jainism* are also religions branched from India. Usually religions have more to do with organized way of worshipping. They often help upholding *Dharma* due to its usually well defined guidelines.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria In Satya Yuga there will be no Religion or cities. People just live in forests and do Tapasya. Satya Yuga is Saatvic and way of life is different from Kali Yuga.

Comment: I didnt get my answer sir...i mean what were the religion of people during treta and dwapar yuga except hinduism. Were there any other people as in non hindus??

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Not just since the Satya Yuga, Jainism has been around since some previous Manvantara.  Rishabha was a descendant of the ancient king Priyavarta, who ruled in the Swayambhuva Manvantara.

Comment: @AnilKumar Where in the world did you hear that there were no cities in the Satya Yuga?  It's true that Tapasya was the standard way of worship in the Satya Yuga, just as Yagnas were the standard way of worship in the Treta Yuga and so on, but that does not mean that everyone just spent their lives engaging in Tapasya.  There were definitely cities and people following the Vedas and all that.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Brahmanda and Linga Purana. People live in forests (may be in hermitages). May be there was no name for that faith as Jainism in Satya Yuga.

Comment: @AnilKumar Do you know what chapters of the Brahmanda and Linga Purana mention this?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yeah I know, I was just talking about the current cycle of the 24 tirthankars. Jainism yuga theory is similar to Sri Yukteswar's yuga theory. Their texts say that Rishabhadeva was the founder of Jainism in the current half cycle.

Comment: Sir i guess thats not my answer.

Comment: Somewhat related--There is a mention of creation of a "false religion" in scriptures at the time when the three cities Tripura existed.Lord Vishnu (being the Lord of Maya(illusion/ignorance),who could have done it better)) created a bald man who was supposed to teach a false religion to the inhabitants of the Tripura as was taught to him by the Lord Himself.This was necessary to delude the asuras and take them away from the regular Shiva worship they were doing.Otherwsise, the 3 cities could not have been destroyed.Finally, as is well known, Lord Shiva destroyed Tripura.

Comment: *And the intersting part is that the bald man and his accomplices were to re appear in a desert area in kali yuga where they will again have to resume preaching the false religion.So,everything is falling into place .:)

Comment: Sir what religion was he preaching? Related to hinduism?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Please don't call me sir .Treat me like your brother or a friend. :)

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi It was a false religion .So Lord Vishnu taught the bald man dressed in white to preach adharma precisely.Santana Dharma is the only true religion & all others are fake ones.This was necessary to prevent the three brother asuras of Tripura from worshipping Lord Shiva.Otherwise the punya that they were getting and also the protection that they were getting from Lord Shiva would have made the destruction of Tripura impossible.But it was absolutely necessary to destroy the 3 cities which later on Lord Shiva did and there by came to be known as Tripurantakari

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi * But after the destruction of the 3 cities the bald man came & asked Lord Vishnu-" What shall i do now considering that the purpose of my creation has been served?"The Lord answered that you will have to wait till kali yuga when again you need to resume preaching this false dharma in a desert.According to Bhavisya purana too, the re inacranation of tripurasura is said to create a barabaric religion.in the desert of which you must be quite aware of .:)

Comment: all religions are anadhi and nithya.. take all abharamic religion they trace the beginning to Abhraham the formless god worship was there before jesus, moses was the prophet  for both muslims and christians. Pagans where there before and now also in few places.. similarly before gaudapada advaita was there as there was reference bhisma about the key advaitic concepts  and refuting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rig veda [I.110](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01110.htm) says about Ṛbhus

> 2. When, seeking your enjoyment onward from afar, ye, certain of my kinsmen, **wandered on your way, Sons of Sudhanvan**, after your long
>    journeying, ye came unto the home of liberal Savitar.
> 3. ***Savitar therefore gave you immortality***, because ye came proclaiming him whom naught can hide; And this the drinking-chalice of
>    the Asura, which till that time was one, ye made to be fourfold.

These mantras are talking about existence of different methods/religious rituals in Vedic Era, other than Spirituality.

Here **immortality** does not indicate a boon to live forever,which in the subsequent literature described as **chiranjIvatva**, but only permanent BLISS emanated out of SELF REALISATION.

---

In Ramayana, Sri Hanuman was described as the follower of **dakshinAchAra** - Vedic way of life.

> अञ्जलिं प्राङ्मुखः कृत्वा पवनायात्मयोओनयो | ततो हि ववृधे गन्तुं
> **दक्षिणो** दक्षिणां दिश्म् || ५-१-९
>
> Hanuma, follower of **dakshinAchAra**, turned towards east, saluted his father, the Lord of Wind and
> increased his body to go towards southern direction.

In this sloka **दक्षिणो** indicates follower of **dakshinAchAra**, दक्षिणां दिश्म् indicates in Southern direction.

So there existed vAmAchAra - the way of life that opposed to vedic way of life.

---

**In Mahabharata**

While giving away her ear rings, the queen of king Paushya, [she warns Utanka](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01004.htm) about King of Serpants, Takshaka, who is waiting to steal those ear rings.

> 'These ear-rings are very much sought after by Takshaka, the King of
> the serpents. Therefore shouldst thou carry them with the greatest
> care.'
>
> On the road Utanka perceived coming towards him a ***naked idle beggar***
> sometimes coming in view and sometimes disappearing. And Utanka put
> the ear-rings on the ground and went for water. In the meantime the
> beggar came quickly to the spot and taking up the ear-rings ran away.

Narrating appearance of Takshaka  in the form of a naked beggar, **might be a pot shot against Jainism**, which existed at the time of composition of Mahabharata in Classical Sanskrit.