# In the Vedas, is there a teaching which supports life after death or resurrection?

Tags: vedas

I knew that Vedic religion is different somehow from Hinduism. Was Vedas or Vedic religion teaching somewhat of life after death or resurrection, either alone or beside reincarnation?

Comment: Are you expecting answer on resurrection, apart from Jesus or reincarnation  in terms of Veda only or incidents occurred in the recent past?

Comment: @srimannarayana I mean resurrection of the dead, not resurrection of Jesus, in terms of Veda, i.e: is Veda teaching resurrection of the dead or reincarnation or both of them?

Comment: Reviving a dead person, was mentioned in Rig Veda and brAhmanas. I doubt about reincarnation, though AGNI was eulogised as knower of all births - jAtaveda

Comment: is not life after death, means soul gets a different body in some other/same species which is what is suppose to be reincarnation? Resurrection i understand to be coming alive in the same body.

Comment: @PrakashK I Resurrection is either in the same body or in a new body, but in both cases the memory doesn't be lost, i.e: the resurrected remember his memories.

Answer (score 1):

> Was Vedas or Vedic religion teaching somewhat of life after death or resurrection, either alone or beside reincarnation?

Vedic religion is the same as Hinduism. Hinduism is literally the religion based on the Vedas. Hence, there is no difference between the "Vedic religion" and Hinduism, although some practices have changed overtime.

But to answer your question, I'm not aware of resurrection, but the Vedas definitely do talk about life after death. For example, the *Taittiriya Brahmana* says the soul of the sacrificed horse goes to Yama loka:

> They (the Samitars, the slaughterers) kill the horse (literally: cause the horse to acquiesce) by means of the tArpya cloth. The tArpya cloth surely is the sacrifice. They thus abundantly provide him with (the essence of) the sacrifice. The Prastotar worships (the horse) by singing the Saman that belongs to Yama. He thus sends him to Yama loka. - 3.9.20

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why folks keep alluding to Hinduism or it's branches like vaishnavism , shaivism etc as being different from Vedic religion. It is because of such thoughts people coined the negative Brahminism term

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> I knew that Vedic religion is different somehow from Hinduism.
>
> Was Vedas or Vedic religion teaching somewhat of life after death or
>   resurrection, either alone or beside reincarnation?

---

We should call Vedic **way of life** but not Vedic religion.  During Vedic era, people used to have [different methods of worshipping God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37670/3869).

The Veda tell us about SPIRITUALITY, which involves SELF EXAMINATION, pursuing practices which result in SELF REALISATION.

- A Religion should have a SUPREME GOD, a holy text, certain rituals to be followed, etc.
- Islam, Christianity, Buddhism, Shaivism, Vaishnavism, etc, are religions.
- Yes, major aspects of present day Hinduism are different from Vedic way of life, except SPIRITUAL practices.

---

### Life of after death or resurrection

1) It is a mysterious issue.  Except seers no one will be able to explain this issue with **First hand experience**, other than quoting from scriptures.

Rig Veda mentions about AGNI or BRAHMAN or the Almighty as knower of all births - **jAtaveda** (Rig Veda [III.29.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv03029.htm))

> araṇyornihito **jātavedā** gharbha iva sudhito gharbhiṇīṣu | dive-diva
>   īḍyo jāghṛvadbhirhaviṣmadbhirmanuṣyebhiraghniḥ ||
>
> 1n the two fire-sticks **Jātavedas** lieth, even as the well-set germ in
>   pregnant women, Agni who day by day must be exalted by men who watch
>   and worship with oblations.

---

2) Upon Dadhyanc a horse head is placed by the Asvins, who wish to learn his knowledge (RIG VEDA [1-117-22](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01117.htm)).

> Ye brought the horse's head, Aśvins, and gave it unto Dadhyac the
>   offspring of Atharvan. True, he revealed to you, O Wonder-Workers,
>   sweet Soma, Tvaṣṭar's secret, as your girdle.

The story of **replacement with horse head** unto **Dadhyac by Aswins** is a mysterious story.  Though it has to be viewed in esoteric sense, but it may be referring to something mysterious thing that occurred at that point of time - **revival of dead**.

[image]